# django template - forloop.counter for every 5 entries

Tags: python, django

I have a template as per below, so far I have used the grouper to group my showrooms alphabetically and insert the letter, which works great. However for ease of display I would like to put my data in columns, so for every 5 letters of the alphabet i am trying to insert a class (detail-column) that will float each group of 5 letters to create my colummns.

I'm not sure how i reset the loop counter? searching it doesn't seem possible and I would need to write something manually, but I am unsure of the logic I would need to insert this class?

```
{% extends 'home/base-wide.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id='content-body'>
{% include 'service/sidebar.html' %}
    <div class="float-left-content">
    {% regroup Showrooms by location.0 as Showrooms_by_letter %}
    {% for letter_items in Showrooms_by_letter %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 5 %}
        <div class="detail-column">
        {% endif %}
            <h4>{{ letter_items.grouper }}</h4>
                {% for item in letter_items.list %}
                    <div class="letter-link"><a href="{% url 'service:showroom_detail' item.id %}">{{ item.location}}</a></div>
                {% endfor %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 5 %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}             
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need:

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"5" %}
```

django doc about [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby).

Comment: This will not work in django template engine

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov Yea I was out of my mind when I first answer it. Will be more careful next time.